# Adding a constant to the name of a variable in C

Tags: c, variables, concatenation

What I would like to ask is if there is a way to declare a variable with an index (that I get through my program) and append it to my variable name. An example of that could be:

```
char mq_[index] = "Typical string";
```

Where the name of the char would be `mq_1`, `mq_2`, and so on..
Is that possible to do?

Comment: Sounds like you want an array

Comment: @user694733 In trying to clarify the question I think I've just confused myself!

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284738). What are you really trying to solve?

Comment: For some reason, every beginner does at some point get the idea that they need to change variable names based on run-time events. Doing so does not make any sense, since variable names only exist for benefit of the programmer, when they are making the program. Variable names fill no other purpose and they are not part of the executable.

Comment: Confused with, what you asking?

Comment: Not sure about the full flow defining the variable name, however as it has been mentioned, the only way is to set it during the parser phase. A starting point would be something like this:


#define _getVarName(var)  #var

which can then be used like:

int myVar = 123;
printf("var name %s, _getVarName(myVar);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Variable names are not present when C code is executed (typically), since they are removed by the compiler.

C is not typically a "dynamic" language, you can't generate source and have it evaluated at run-time since the typical run-time environment does not include a C compiler.

If you want an array of strings which you can index, use use an array of strings and an index:

```
const char *strings[] = { "Hello", "these", "are", "strings" };
const int index = 2;

puts(strings[index]);
```

This will print `are`, the third element in the array. Remember that C arrays index from 0.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Unless the variable is declared `extern` so that the linker needs to know about it, the name of the variable is completely unavailable to the program at run time (excepting that there might be a symbol table for the debugger).

If you are attempting to add an index to the variable, why not use an array instead?

Comment: Linking is still before run time, even `extern`ed variable names won't be present when the code runs. The linker resolves the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define the variable name dynamically. In your case you should use an array.

```
char *mq[] = {
    "Typical string",
    "Typical string",
    "Typical string"
};

printf("%s", mq[1]);
```

Comment: And if i wanted to define this as an array of message queues, would it be possible? I tried snatching some code together but it is bonkers..

Comment: Tell us what exactly do you want to do and maybe we can help you more easily. For example if you to make communicate two processe then you can use an IPC (https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node25.html) instead of reinventing the wheel.